# How to create an array of ints filled with 0s in c?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create an array of ints, of a specified size "size." Each member of the array should be filled with 32 0s (since that's the maximum an unsigned int can take). How should I go about this? Right now I have:

```
unsigned int *new_array = (unsigned int*) malloc (sizeof(unsigned int) * size);
for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    new_array[j] = 0;
}
```

Yet when I print new_array[0], I get 0, not 00000000000000000000000000000000. Would bitwise operations help here?

Comment: try `printf("%032u", new_array[0]);`

Comment: An `int` can only hold an `int`.  You might be able to encode 32 bits into an int (if ints on your target are 32 bits), but if you then print that as an int, you'll get an int, not the 32 bits.

Comment: It would be simpler (and more efficient) to use `calloc` instead of malloc with a loop

Comment: Hmm...haven't learned that but I guess now's the time. Thanks @M.M.

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-representation-of-a-given-number/ for a short function that prints the binary sequence

Comment: Re "*since that's the maximum an unsigned int can take*", That's not true. An `unsigned int` might be less than 32 bits, less than 32 bits, or more than 32 bits. It depends on the system and compiler. Use `uint32_t` to get an unsigned integer exactly 32 bits in size.

Comment: It seems that the title and description are rather misleading. The problem is not related to filling the array but only to printing integers. Printing in binary format is not mentioned in the question but for some reasons integers are expected to be a sequence of 32 `0` digits. Additionally the code for printing is not shown. Very confusing...

Answer (score 0):

1. Printing in binary isn't well supported in C, you'll need to [roll your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format) at some level. Might just be easier to print hex.
2. Leading zeroes aren't output by `printf` by default. Use `%08x` to print an 8-digit hex number (32 bits) with leading zeroes.
3. You can call `calloc` to get a zero-initialized array, which would let you skip your `for` loop.
4. [Don't cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: So, even if the program doesn't show it, every element of the int is indeed filled with zeroes? So, is my code right even if it isn't printing right?

Comment: 1. Yes, it's filled with zeros. 2. It is printing right. You asked for a decimal representation of an `int` and that's what it gave you.